# gradle multiproject native build calling build task on dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a multiproject build with the following structure:

```
project(":a") {
    apply plugin: 'cpp'
    model {
        buildTypes {
            release
        }
        components {
            a(NativeExecutableSpec) {
                sources {
                    cpp {
                        lib project: ":b", library: 'b', linkage: 'shared'
                        lib project: ":c", library: 'c', linkage: 'shared'
                        source {
                            srcDir "."
                            include "*.cpp"
                        }
                        exportedHeaders {
                            srcDir "."
                            include "*.h"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project `a` can potentially have many library dependencies like `b`, `c`. And there can be many projects like `a`.

How can I make sure that when I say `gradle ":a:build"`, the build tasks for dependencies are also called?

I know I can say `build.dependsOn(":b:build", ...)` but it seems superfluous since I've already declared that the project `b` is a dependency. So what is the shortest/most reusable way to achieve this?

## Edit

I forgot to add that the library `b` is a prebuilt library. The reason I want to do it this way is that:

- the library `b` is built with a makefile using exec task (I would like to preserve the original build system of the library)
- I would like to depend only on project `b` and not on `:b:build` in my build tasks
- I wouldn't like to specify linker arguments like `-lb`

Comment: Doesn't it happen automatically?

Comment: @Opal yes it does. Please see my edit